# How do I include code snippets (not objects) in an Arduino program?

Tags: arduino, include

Problem Solved!!! See below for solution

I was about to post this question and decided to check the web one more time.  This site https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu40.html 
has this statement:  The {$I filename} or {$INCLUDE filename} directive tells the compiler to read further statements from the file filename. The statements read there will be inserted as if they occurred in the current file.
This is exactly what I want to do with Arduino.  How do I do it?

My Skill Set: 
Writing code since 1967.  Yes, I survived Y2K, which was a real thing; so I'm not new to programming/debugging.  Mainframes and PC's.  Very solid COBOL and SAS skills.  Good skills with Borland/Lazarus Object Pascal.  Weak C/C++ skills.

Background:
I have two working Arduino programs that are used on a model railroad.  Prog1 uses infrared sensors to light LEDs that indicate the position of a train in a tunnel.  I built the IRSensor class to handle a single sensor.  Prog2 uses push-buttons to set a route through several track switches.  Each track switch is set via a servo.  I extended the Servo class to TOServo, which encapsulate most of the commonality in each track switch.

Now I'm working on a different model railroad and need merge Prog1 and Prog2 into a single program.  Building Prog3 via copy/paste from programs 1 & 2 has proved unwieldy.

Problem:
How do I tell the Arduino pre-processor/compiler to "insert filename here; do not compile, pre-compile, or otherwise process the filename unless it is wrapped around the file asking for the insertion"?

What I've tried:
I built Prog3 by separating the code for Prog2 into 3 sections -- Main program storage & code and 2 include statements (Storage definitions and executable code for TOServo).  These include statements pull in code that define or access an array of TOServo.  I've used several suffixes (.h/.ino and .h/.cpp and .c/.c), and they all generate 'not declared in this scope' errors.

Finally:
Thanks for your help.

---

SOLUTION
My .ino file had grown large & unwieldy.  The 'solution' was to move a large segment of code and matching declarations to external .h/.cpp files, and to access those files via #include statements.  The program would not compile (undefined variables); they were, in fact, defined but the compiler couldn't find them.  After many attempts to fix or rearrange the code, finally two things dawned on me.

1)The Arduino pre-compiler changes (rearranges?) my code so that C++ and the Arduino CPU can work together.  This means that the code I see is not always the code the compiler sees.

2)My .h/.cpp files define and manage an array of servo objects.  I could convert those files into an object that I access from the main .ino file.

So I've solved my problem.  Thanks to all those who have posted in many forums/sites, especially to Tarick Welling who stayed with me to the end.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question? (in the form of a minimal reproducible example) stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I'm having trouble with understanding your: "unless it is wrapped around the file asking for the insertion"?"

Comment: Tarick ... I've been pulled into a conference that runs till Sunday; it's all day and early evening.  I will try to get the code posted by Saturday.

Comment: Let's start again.

Comment: Hey I'm still watching this post to help so if you still have a problem...

Comment: I'm still here and still have the problem.  I didn't figure out how to load code to stackoverflow, so I took a different tack.  Go to lastnamesoftware.net/Wiki5/arduino_prob01  It is a wiki that you can browse in any order.  All my code is there along with an explanation of the code structure I'm striving for.  I'm pretty sure that the problem stems from mixing '#include class' and '#include regular_code' in the same program.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: The question can be edited by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56551925/edit) under your question. Code can be added by copy and pasting it in and enclosing it in three [grave accent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6KQb.png) characters. The best way is to add your code in seperate blocks per file. Here is a reference to the [editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: great to see you've solved your problem, it sounds like the correct solution which I also would've given. It would be best if you would add that answer to your own question as an answer. This will help further people who might be in need of this kind of answer find it in its logical place.